# Android Triple Hybrid Application

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to create an application for Android. My application will need to be a service that runs in the background, a UI application for configuring the service, and a desktop widget for turning the background service off and on.

My question is, how is this typically done in android? Do I need 3 separate applications? Or can I create one application that contains my service, my UI and my widget? I know of applications that do this, such as Weather.com, which has a desktop widget, a service which sits in the notification area and a UI application for configuring the service and widget. Weather.Com is a single download from the market, so I'm assuming this can be done in one application. Can someone please point me in the direction of a tutorial or code examples for doing this?

Comment: Maybe because it seems that you didn't search on your own much.

Comment: Maybe because an a detailed answer sat here for eight hours (you visited the site many times in that period) and you didn't bother to accept it as you haven't bothered to accept any answer since July 22.  So, the ansewr deleted and the question voted down.

Comment: July 22 was more than three weeks ago

Comment: @Earl - and FYI dude, Mark is right. I sometimes like to keep an answer open for a few days so I can see a variety of answers. Doesn't mean I just completely ignore them.

Comment: @Earl - One other thing. Just because I am logging onto this site many times doesn't mean I'm here to check my answer. I was on here reading an answer to someone's question unrelated to my own. It doesn't mean I'm sitting here at my computer psycho-refreshing my browser.

Comment: Good, just as I suspected. So we can all chillax and have a nice weekend! I upvoted the question so it's at zero now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course only one application.
Search for appwidget tutorials, there are plenty. You'll get broadcasts for your widget which you handle in one class. Another class for the GUI stuff (well, at least one) and another one for the service. You declare each part in the manifest, so your GUI will have an "Activity" declaration there, your service a "Service" and for the widget a "Receiver":

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" />

<service android:name="MainService" />

<receiver 
    android:name="MyWidget" 
    android:label="MyWidget Desc" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data 
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider" 
        android:resource="@xml/widget_info" 
        />
</receiver>
```

Comment: Don't bother to answer his questions, he doesn't accept them anymore -- not since July 22 --  so you won't get credit.  I had a very detailed with an example from an app in the app store and he took the advice and didn't leave a check, so I deleted it.

Comment: @Earl - Just so you know, I never saw an answer from you regarding an answer to this question. But Mark here did answer it, so I will mark it as right.